# OpenShift In Action - Chapter 6

Tags: openshift-origin

I'm working through using a template from minishift on my mac.  The step is to create a project and download a template (below).

Then to use the template to start up a new application(below 2).

3 of the 4 pods come up correctly (gogs, mongodb, postgresql-gogs), but the 4th pod does generate a deployement (todo-app-flask-mongo).  The error states "Reason: cannot trigger a deployment for todo-app-flask-mongo because it contains unresolved images.

How can I further troubleshoot this and resolve the issue?  I've tried to instantiate both via the command line and the web console.

```
oc create -f \                                                       1
    https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OpenShiftInAction/
    chapter6/master/openshift-cicd-flask-mongo/OpenShift/templates/
    dev-todo-app-flask-mongo-gogs.json \                                2
    -n dev      

oc new-app --template="dev/dev-todo-app-flask-mongo-gogs"
--> Deploying template "dev/todo-app-flask-mongo-gogs" to project dev
 Flask + MongoDB (Ephemeral)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've imported the template via the UI - the applications gogs, postgresql-gogs and mongodb are running successfully. The build in the deployment config "todo-app-flask-mongo"is not started automatically, because I guess there is currently no trigger defined.

I triggered the build manually in the UI - as described in the picture

[image]

The build ran into an error, because the [template](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OpenShiftInAction/chapter6/master/openshift-cicd-flask-mongo/OpenShift/templates/dev-todo-app-flask-mongo-gogs.json) youre importing is having a [typo](https://github.com/OpenShiftInAction/chapter6/blob/6c1ba00710fb7f5a92a4bad3a5102733c5e5fffe/openshift-cicd-flask-mongo/OpenShift/templates/dev-todo-app-flask-mongo-gogs.json#L366)

Just import the template via the UI and fix the line by adding a curly bracket "}"

After doing so, the "todo-app-flask-mongo" build is working and will start a pod afterwards - which you can access by the generated route.

Comment: Thank you!  I appreciate the thorough explanation.  How did you find the typo?  I wasn't sure how to further diagnose.  Thanks again!

Comment: After starting the build for "todo-app-flask-mongo" you can visit the "Builds" -section and click on the last build and check the "Logs" tab in there. The output you're seeing there is something like:

* Cloning "${GIT_URI" ...
* error: fatal: '${GIT_URI' does not appear to be a git repository.


There you can see that there is an issue with that GIT_URI param.

Comment: I was able to edit the template on the command line (on Linux) like this: 
`oc edit template dev-todo-app-flask-mongo-gogs` .
My default editor is vi but this will depend on your profile.

Comment: Note that I had to delete the project, import the template, edit it with the "oc edit" command above, and then did the rest of it as stated in the book. I was able to build successfully from the GUI.